# How to use the Spearman's rank correlation in R

Tags: r, spearman-rho

I used three methods (M1, M2 and M3) to generate rankings, which is the `result` database.

```
 result<-structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
     12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
     28, 29), M1 = c(29L, 1L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
     22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
     8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M2 = c(1, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 
    24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 
   8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), M3 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 
   20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 
   2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-29L))

> result
    n M1 M2 M3
1   1 29  1  1
2   2  1 29 29
3   3 28 28 28
4   4 27 27 27
5   5 25 26 25
6   6 26 25 26
7   7 24 24 24
8   8 20 23 20
9   9 21 22 21
10 10 22 21 22
11 11 23 20 23
12 12 15 15 15
13 13 12 12 12
14 14 17 19 17
15 15 18 18 18
16 16 19 17 19
17 17 16 16 16
18 18 13 14 13
19 19 14 13 14
20 20  5 11  5
21 21  6 10  6
22 22  7  9  7
23 23  8  8  8
24 24  9  7  9
25 25 10  6 10
26 26 11  5 11
27 27  4  4  4
28 28  2  3  2
29 29  3  2  3
```

Now, I would like to use the Spearman's rank correlation considering this database above. Therefore, Spearman's rank correlation coefficient between the $k$th and $i$th methods is calculated by the following equation:

$$\rho_{ki} = 1 - \frac{6\sum{d_i^2}}{n(n^2-1)},$$

where $n$ is the number of alternatives and $d_i$ is the difference between the ranks of two methods.

Can you help me solve this issue above?

Without using the `cor` function, it would look like this?

```
 dif <- result %>% 
    mutate(D1 = M1-M2, D2 = M1-M3, D3 = M2-M3)
  
  d <-dif$D1
  
  rho <- function(d) {
    1 - (6 * (sum(d)^2) / (length(d) * ((length(d)^2) - 1)))
  }
  
  rho(d)
```

Comment: cor(result, method = "spearman")

Comment: Nick, thanks for reply. Please, Can you look at the question again? I wanted to do it without using the `cor` function, would it be more or less the same as I did above? But the results did not match the results of `cor` function.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Since you have already produced the ranks*, you can take the Pearson correlation of these rank-transformed data to obtain the Spearman correlation. Only using very basic functions in R, which seems to be what you want to do, you could do:

`sum((M1-mean(M1)) * (M2-mean(M2))) / (length(M1)-1)  / (sd(M1)*sd(M2))`

That is, you are using the obvious estimator for the definition

$$\rho = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_x\ \sigma_y}$$

This will produce the same as `cor(M1, M2, method = "spearman")` and also the same as `cor(M1, M2, method = "pearson")`.

The formula you posted gets into deep trouble when there are many ties, which is exactly the case in your dataset.